# Export multiple dataframe to multiple excel file with pandas

Tags: pandas

My DataFrame is in loop like x=1,2,5,6

dfx

```
Dataframe :  df1,df2,df5,df6
```

filepath;

```
file1 = 'G:\\python\\out\\consumption_rice_1.xlsx'
file2 = 'G:\\python\\out\\consumption_rice_2.xlsx'
file5 = 'G:\\python\\out\\consumption_rice_5.xlsx'
file6 = 'G:\\python\\out\\consumption_rice_6.xlsx'
```

Want to export df1 to file1 , ..., df6 to file6.

Please help me how do export with  loop .

Answer (score 2):

You can export to one excel file with multiple sheets after the loop. For Ex-

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('consumption_rice.xlsx')
df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
df2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2')
df3.to_excel(writer,'Sheet3')
df4.to_excel(writer,'Sheet4')
writer.save()
```

**Demo:** https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_multiple.html

If you still want multiple `.xlsx` then try this with looping(Not tested though)

```
df_list = [df1,df2,df3,df4]
for key, df in df_list:
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('consumption_rice_'+key+'.xlsx')
    df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
    writer.save()
```